# Elasticsearch doesn't initialize in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am updating the spring boot version of my applications to a version, in case I was using version 1.3.2 I am now migrating to 1.4.3. So my Elasticsearch is giving the following error.

```
2017-06-01 10:41:28.449  WARN 12480 --- [ I/O worker #1}] org.elasticsearch.transport.netty        : [Maxam] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x12666e2c, /192.168.1.9:63584 => /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9300]], closing connection

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class SearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public Client elasticsearchClient() throws UnknownHostException {

        Settings settings = Settings
                            .settingsBuilder()
                            .put("cluster.name", "production-1")
                            .build();

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");

        InetSocketTransportAddress transportAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(address, 9300);

        return TransportClient
                .builder()
                .settings(settings)
                .build()
                    .addTransportAddress(transportAddress);

    }
```

**Application**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "br.com.projectx" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.projectx.devices.commands.search" })
@EnableRedisRepositories
@EnableAsync
public class Application { ... }
```

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>projectx-endpoint-devices-commands</artifactId>
    <groupId>br.com.projectx</groupId>
    <description>Commands Endpoints</description>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1-beta</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jmethods</groupId>
            <artifactId>catatumbo</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <version>0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>



</project>
```

Comment: Share pom.xml please.

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF added

Comment: Check that all elasticsearch instances (nodes) are shutdown and restart your app. See this issue in ES https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14400

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF Problem is in version, I'm using seach 1.5

Comment: You should use ES from 2.0.0 to 5.0.0 . See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix

Comment: I added this as an answer. It could be helpful for someone else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spring-boot:1.4.3` is not compatible with elasticsearch 1.x versions hence it has a dependency on `spring-data-elasticsearch:2.0.6.RELEASE`.

You should use elasticsearch version between 2.0.0 and 5.0.0. See [Spring Data Elasticsearch Spring Boot version matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix)